# Polygamy in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Apparently there is more than one way to acquire the Amulet of Mara which is required in order to get married.

Is it possible to be married to more than one partner at the same time?

Comment: The Amulet of Mara isn't given to your partner, it's just worn to let folks know you're "on the market".

Comment: @RavenDreamer my mistake, do potiential partners still think of you as "on the market" even though you may already have a spouse?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No.

Wearing the Amulet of Mara while you're married no longer triggers dialog options. You must kill your current spouse and wear the amulet to bring up potential "Are you interested" dialog options again.

Comment: +1 *sigh* though you'd think polygamy would be less offensive than familicide. Yet the second is allowed. Yay for mods?

Comment: Well then I guess someone needs to test, if you slay your spouse and then marry someone else and raise you dead spouse... :)

Comment: ...only to watch your zombie spouse dissolve into a pile of ashes 60 seconds later.  :(

Comment: Hmm, yes, but then you could tap that ash..

Comment: "tap that ash" sounds like a bad pokemon reference

Comment: There's probably some console code to circumvent this. @DaveSherohman: [Thrall](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dead_Thrall)

Comment: Don't even need a console command. There's a helmet that let's you copy a the ritual stone ability, and then you can just rez them forever! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tmWY1ekyyi0

Answer (score 2):

This mod claims to allow polygamy.

Marriage Mod - To Have & To Hold

http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=11579&tscn=1335929394

Answer (score -1):

You could kill your spouse then marry again then do the console command "resurrect" on your dead spouse and then you have 2.

Comment: When your spouse dies, that's it. You can't remarry. It *might* be possible to work some setStage magic with this theory, but it'd be complicated.